# Detecting mulitple cycles in a cyclic directed graph

Tags: python, graph-theory, cycle, directed-graph

I have a directed cyclic graph with more than one cycle in it and I need a way to detect (and list) each cycle present in the digraph.

The graph can be seen here: http://img412.imageshack.us/img412/3327/schematic.gif

This is a dummy graph put together for the sake of debugging my python script. It contains the cycles:

`[n13, n14], [n6, n8, n15, n16, n7], [n6, n8, n9, n7]`

The algorithm must detect every cycle in the digraph, not just the smallest nor the first it encounters.

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60196714/1763149

Answer (score 2):

You didn't really specify how you represent the Directed graph, but you can have a look at [Neopythonic:Detecting Cycles in directed graph](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2009/01/detecting-cycles-in-directed-graph.html).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, python-graph only finds one cycle, not all posible cycles. See:

http://groups.google.com/group/python-graph/browse_thread/thread/9170926f1bdd097b

This other article seems to solve the problem presented in this question:

http://www.bitformation.com/art/python_toposort.html

It's using the algorithm devised by R. E. Tarjan in 1972

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try and use this [library](http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/). It has a cycle detection algorithm.