# How to detect a cycle in a directed graph with Python?

Tags: python, graph-theory

I have some input like: `[('A', 'B'),('C', 'D'),('D', 'C'),('C', 'D')]`. I want to look for if the existence of a cycle in a directed graph represented by this edgeList.

I read a discussion: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-in-a-graph/, however it has some errors when the case is:

```
g = Graph(3)
g.addEdge('A', 'B')
g.addEdge('B', 'C')
g.addEdge('C', 'A')
```

Its result is 'Graph has no cycle'. This is clearly wrong.
Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Try the networkx library.

Comment: What have you tried so far (please show a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))? Do you want to know how to find cycles in a graph or how to implement a given detector algorithm in python?

Comment: Relevant https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding all cycles in a directed graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546655/finding-all-cycles-in-a-directed-graph)

Answer (score 13):

Using the [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/) library, we can use the [`simple_cycles`](https://networkx.github.io/) function to find all simple cycles of a directed Graph.

**Example Code:**

```
import networkx as nx

edges = [('A', 'B'),('C', 'D'),('D', 'C'),('C', 'D')]

G = nx.DiGraph(edges)

for cycle in nx.simple_cycles(G):
    print(cycle)

G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edge('A', 'B')
G.add_edge('B', 'C')
G.add_edge('C', 'A')

for cycle in nx.simple_cycles(G):
    print(cycle)
```

**Output:**

```
['D', 'C']
['B', 'C', 'A']
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the example given at [1]: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-in-a-graph/ works for integers only because they use the `range()` function to create a list of nodes,see the line

```
for node in range(self.V):
```

That makes the assumption that not only will all the nodes be integers but also that they will be a contiguous set i.e. `[0,1,2,3]` is okay but `[0,3,10]` is not.

You can fix the example if you like to work with any nodes by swapping the line given above with

```
for node in self.graph.keys():
```

which will loop through all the nodes instead of a range of numbers :)

Answer (score 1):

My own implementation (non-recursive so without cycle length limit):

```py
from collections import defaultdict


def has_cycle(graph):
    try:
        next(_iter_cycles(graph))
    except StopIteration:
        return False
    return True


def _iter_cycles(edges):
    """Iterate over simple cycles in the directed graph."""
    if isinstance(edges, dict):
        graph = edges
    else:
        graph = defaultdict(set)
        for x, y in edges:
            graph[x].add(y)
    SEP = object()
    checked_nodes = set()  # already checked nodes
    for start_node in graph:
        if start_node in checked_nodes:
            continue
        nodes_left = [start_node]
        path = []         # current path from start_node
        node_idx = {}     # {node: path.index(node)}
        while nodes_left:
            node = nodes_left.pop()
            if node is SEP:
                checked_node = path.pop()
                del node_idx[checked_node]
                checked_nodes.add(checked_node)
                continue
            if node in checked_nodes:
                continue
            if node in node_idx:
                cycle_path = path[node_idx[node]:]
                cycle_path.append(node)
                yield cycle_path
                continue
            next_nodes = graph.get(node)
            if not next_nodes:
                checked_nodes.add(node)
                continue
            node_idx[node] = len(path)
            path.append(node)
            nodes_left.append(SEP)
            nodes_left.extend(next_nodes)


assert not has_cycle({0: [1, 2], 1: [3, 4], 5: [6, 7]})
assert has_cycle([(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1)])


def assert_cycles(graph, expected):
    detected = sorted(_iter_cycles(graph))
    if detected != expected:
        raise Exception('expected cycles:\n{}\ndetected cycles:\n{}'.format(expected, detected))


assert_cycles([('A', 'B'),('C', 'D'),('D', 'C'),('C', 'D')], [['C', 'D', 'C']])
assert_cycles([('A', 'B'),('B', 'A'),('B', 'C'),('C', 'B')], [['A', 'B', 'A'], ['B', 'C', 'B']])

assert_cycles({1: [2, 3], 2: [3, 4]}, [])
assert_cycles([(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 4)], [])

assert_cycles({1: [2, 4], 2: [3, 4], 3: [1]}, [[1, 2, 3, 1]])
assert_cycles([(1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1)], [[1, 2, 3, 1]])

assert_cycles({0: [1, 2], 2: [3], 3: [4], 4: [2]}, [[2, 3, 4, 2]])
assert_cycles([(0, 1), (0, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 2)], [[2, 3, 4, 2]])

assert_cycles({1: [2], 3: [4], 4: [5], 5: [3]}, [[3, 4, 5, 3]])
assert_cycles([(1, 2), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 3)], [[3, 4, 5, 3]])

assert_cycles({0: [], 1: []}, [])
assert_cycles([], [])

assert_cycles({0: [1, 2], 1: [3, 4], 5: [6, 7]}, [])
assert_cycles([(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (5, 6), (5, 7)], [])

assert_cycles({0: [1], 1: [0, 2], 2: [1]}, [[0, 1, 0], [1, 2, 1]])
assert_cycles([(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1)], [[0, 1, 0], [1, 2, 1]])
```

EDIT:

I found that while `has_cycle` seems to be correct,
the `_iter_cycles` does **not** iterate over **all** cycles!

Example in which `_iter_cycles` does not find all cycles:

```
assert_cycles([
        (0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0),  # Cycle 0-1-2
        (0, 2), (2, 0),          # Cycle 0-2
        (0, 1), (1, 4), (4, 0),  # Cycle 0-1-4
    ],
    [
        [0, 1, 2, 0],  # Not found (in Python 3.7)!
        [0, 1, 4, 0],
        [0, 2, 0],
    ]
)
```

Comment: fine, thans so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following function does the job and is 14 lines of code. The idea is to remove edges as we traverse them, starting at the leaves.
I have not checked it exhaustivelly but it works with small graphs.
Also mind that it is not optimized for speed in large graphs.

```py
def get_cycle(DAG):
    ''' DAG is assumed a dict {node: [node,...],...}. 
        DAG keys are children and values (lists of) parents;
        Roots are not DAG keys (since they have no parents).
        
        The function returns the first cycle it will detect as a list 
        of nodes, or an empty list if the DAG has no cycles.        
        NB! the DAG is modified (eventually becomes totally disconnected)
    ''' 
    
    def get_leaves(DAG):
        ''' Return the leaves of the DAG.
            A leaf is not a parent and not a root
        '''
        parents = set(i for v in DAG.values() for i in v)
        return [c for c in DAG if len(DAG[c]) > 0 and c not in parents]

    def ascend(node, DAG, visits):
        ''' Ascend a single path starting at node. 
            When a node is visited, remove it from the DAG.
            If a node is visited multiple times we obviously have a cycle.
        '''
        if len(DAG.get(node, [])) > 0:            
            visits.append(parent := DAG[node].pop())
            ascend(parent, DAG, visits)
        return visits

    def is_bag(lis: List):
        ''' Return True if lis contains multiplicities
        '''
        return len(set(lis)) < len(lis)

    while len(leaves := get_leaves(DAG)) > 0:
        if is_bag(visits := ascend(leaves[0], DAG=DAG, visits=[])):
            return visits
    return []
```