# Detecting cycles in a weighted directed graph with Python

Tags: python, graph-theory

I am pretty new in Python (it is my first code) and I am wondering how can I find all cycles in a WEIGHTED directed graph.

I saw [How to detect a cycle in a directed graph with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59820748/how-to-detect-a-cycle-in-a-directed-graph-with-python) (for graphs without weights), but I did not understand, why there is an edge between 'C' and 'D' mentioned twice and why there is g.addEdge('A', 'B') (this edge is mentioned above).

I tried to write code without weights on my own (I have edges between 
'1' and '2', with weight 2 
'1'and '3', with weight 7 
'2' and '3', with weight -2 
'2' and '4', with weight -4 
'3'and '1', with weight 7 
'3'and '4', with weight 3
'4' and '3', with weight 3) 
but I do not understand, why all my cycles starts with vertex "3" and how to write a code with weights.

My code for directed graph without weights is:

```
edges = [('1', '2'),('1', '3'),('2', '3'),('2', '4'),('3', '1'),('3', '4'),('4', '3')]

G = nx.DiGraph(edges)

for cycle in nx.simple_cycles(G):
    print(cycle)
```

and output is:

```
['3', '4']
['3', '1']
['3', '1', '2', '4']
['3', '1', '2']
```

And I want something like this:

```
['3', '4'] weight 6
['3', '1'] weight 11
['3', '1', '2', '4'] weight 5
['3', '1', '2'] weight 4
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The weights do not matter for finding cycles.

Comment: All the cycles on your graph *include* vertex 3, nothing strange about that. If you understand the definition of cycle you can quickly verify it on a drawing. A cycle doesn't *start* on a given vertex, it is a sequence of vertices.

Comment: @DaniMesejo yes, I know. But I want to find cycles with their costs. I need to proof that in my graph, there are no negative cycles (I need to show it for all possible cycles in graph). I found code which writes if there is or there is not a negative cycle, but it does not write, how many negative cycles there is and their cost.

Comment: So you already have a code that finds all cycles, right?

Comment: @al-dev is it possible to explain, why python chose 3 and it did not start with 1 (and write all cycles containing 1), then 2 (and write all cycles containing 2) etc.?

Comment: @DaniMesejo I think I have. :) I wrote it above and it found all cycles so I assume that it works right.  :) I want to know, how to find cycles WITH WEIGHTS. :)

Comment: So once you have all cycles compute the cost for each of those. Note that your question as it stands is very confusing, please add input and expected output (a small graph and the output you want from it, together with what you have done)

Comment: Your program outputs `['1', '2', '4', '3'] ['1', '2', '3'] ['1', '3'] ['3', '4']` for me, so I don't really understand your statement 'Python chose 3'. If you get a different output and wonder why you should look at the implementation of `simple_cycles` in the networkx library. I have v2.2. But I don't think that's really relevant to your problem. [1,2,3] is the same cycle as [2,3,1]. Does that make sense? You can rotate them however you like.

Comment: @DaniMesejo I edited my question. I appologize for confusing.

Comment: @al-dev I just wondered why it choose 3 (in my case) - it is my first code in python and I tried to understand how it works. :) But it is not relevant to my problem - you are right.

Comment: No problem! Good luck.